# Zebra Striping with PHPTAL?

Tags: php, template-tal, phptal

I'm trying out PHPTAL and I want to render a table with zebra stripes. I'm looping through a simple php assoc array ($_SERVER).

Note that I don't want to use jQuery or anything like that, I'm trying to learn PHPTAL usage!

Currently I have it working like this (too verbose for my liking):

```
<tr tal:repeat="item server">
  <td tal:condition="repeat/item/odd" tal:content="repeat/item/key" class="odd">item key</td>
  <td tal:condition="repeat/item/even" tal:content="repeat/item/key" class="even">item key</td>
  <td tal:condition="repeat/item/odd" tal:content="item" class="odd">item value</td>
  <td tal:condition="repeat/item/even" tal:content="item" class="even">item value</td>
</tr>
```

Basically I want some kind of conditional assignment on the fly, but I'm unsure of the syntax.

Comment: I like the name _zebra striping_. Never heard before and makes perfect sense.

Comment: Note that you can handle this in CSS3, which is advantageous as it leaves design up to the designers:

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #99ff99;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create expression modifier by writing `phptal_tales_evenodd()` function (see `phptal_tales()` in manual):

```
<td tal:attributes="class evenodd:repeat/item/odd">
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems like I have my own answer, though I still think this is rather ugly:

```
<tr tal:repeat="item server">
  <td tal:content="repeat/item/key" tal:attributes="class php: repeat.item.odd ? 'odd' : 'even'">item key</td>
  <td tal:content="item" tal:attributes="class php: repeat.item.odd ? 'odd' : 'even'">item value</td>
</tr>
```

Anyone got anything more graceful looking for PHPTAL?